# EmailValidation (email address) with RFC3696

Tags: java, email, email-validation

I look for an email validator accepted the email address in the rfc3696 standard (who accepted the accents in the email). I try ( org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator) "commons-validator 1.4.0" but this validator does not accept accents.

I want a java api to validates an email address according to standard rfc3696. 
Ex Valid Email address : Loïc.Accentué@voilà.fr

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't you better trying to send the content to the mail provided? If you receive an error you'll know the e-mail is incorrect. Validating e-mails is really tricky.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire getting the error from the mta is even more tricky.

Comment: Do you need validation other than sending an email to the provided address and requiring some response (clicking a link, reply, etc etc)?

Comment: You shouldn't validate e-mails at all. And for a lot of reasons. This link shows some: http://girders.org/blog/2013/01/31/dont-rfc-validate-email-addresses/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution to validate email address is parse email with JavaMail.

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
   try {
       InternetAddress.parse(emailAddress, true);
       return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
   }

}
```